# How do I find the determinant of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm preparing for an exam currently, and I came across this question: [image: The particular question I found]

I have noticed that A can be constructed from the matrix on the left by a series of row operations, so I had the idea maybe to express A as a product of elementary matrices as well as the matrix on the left and, maybe there was some fact about the determinants of elementary matrices? So then I could just use some properties of determinants, as well as knowing that the determinant of the matrix on the left is 2 to figure out $det(A)$

Entirely confused though because I do not know what the determinant of elementary matrices are, and if I should be multiplying all the elementary matrices together etc etc?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Well get the factor $4$ out (i.e. replace first row by $g,h,i$ and consider $\det(A)/4$). Then you van transform the determinant to the one on the left by only row additions subtraction. How is the determinant affected by such operations ?

Comment: Why should it be $\frac{det(A)}{4^3}$ ? This is where im getting confused because im not sure I know the rules for what you can and cant do

Comment: sorry typo, only $4$ because $\det(A)=4g |\cdots|-4h|\cdots|+4i|\cdots|=4\times(g |\cdots|-h|\cdots|+i|\cdots|)$ this is just developping the determinant along terms of first row.

Comment: Oh that makes some more sense, i think, however the answer claims $det(A) = -8$ so im not totally sure how they got there lol

Comment: Because row $g,h,i$ is in first position, while originally it is in last position. Each time you swap rows, you multiply by $-1$ (here swap row1 and row3 one time).

Comment: @HarveyR if an answer solved your question, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark below the voting arrows ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Entirely confused though because I do not know what the determinant of elementary matrices are...

You don't even need to know those elementary matrices. You just need to know **how elementary row operations affect the determinant**. In this case, we need all three types of operations, and I write the effect in the parentheses behind.

1. Multiply a row by a non-zero number. (determinant multiplied by this number)
2. Interchange two rows. (determinant multiplied by $-1$)
3. Add a scalar multiple of one row to another row. (determinant unchanged)

It's obvious that we can multiply the first row of $A$ by $\frac{1}{4}$ and add to the second row (operation type 3) to get $(d\  e\  f)$. Then multiplying this row by $\frac{1}{2}$ and adding to the second row (type 3) gives us a clean row $(a\ b\ c)$. Now we have a matrix that can be related to $A$ by elementary row operations and have the same determinant as $A$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
4g & 4h & 4i\\
d & e & f\\
a & b & c
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Divide the first row by 4  (type 1) and interchange the first and the second last row (type 2), we get the original matrix whose determinant is known to be $2$. Since we know consequences of three types of operation, it's easy to conclude that
$$
\det (A) = -4\times 2=-8
$$

---

P.S.

I personally don't remember those matrices performing elementary row operations as matrix multiplications. And I don't understand the necessity of working out those operation matrces (or the overall matrix $C$ in @Dan's answer). Doing matrix multiplication is always tedious, after all. As I have said, observing that $A$ can be related to the original matrix by row operations suffice to give the answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks for nicely detailing what I hurriedly said in comments, this is effectively the most efficient way to deal with determinants. I would just add that it works similarly with columns operations since $\det(M)=\det(^tM)$

Answer (score 9):

Let $B = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{pmatrix}$.

If you take the operations that transform $B$ into $A$, and apply them to the identity matrix, you get:

$$C = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

So $A = CB$, which means that $\det(A) = \det(C) \det(B)$.  You should be able to calculate that $\det(C) = -4$, and you are given that $\det(B) = 2$.  Therefore, $\det(A) = -8$.

Since this is nonzero, then yes, $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that you could combine the elementary matrices into one matrix like this. From that point I agree, finding $det(C)$ is straightforward. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

If we are uncertain about the row / col transform we could represent it in a matrix multiplication fashion.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4g & 4h & 4i \\
d-g & e-h & f-i \\
a-2d & b-2e & c-2f\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
g & h & i\\
d & e & f\\
a & b & c\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
g & h & i\\
d & e & f\\
a & b & c\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Easy to see
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}=-1\\
\det\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}=4
$$

Since the determinant $\det AB=\det A \det B$

We get $\det A=-4\det
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i\\
\end{bmatrix}=-8 $

$\det A\neq 0$ so it's invertible